# How to find GCF of 2 polynomials?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

"Find smallest natural value of $n$ for which $5n+16$ and $8n +29$ have a common factor $>1$. What are the possible common factors of $5n+16$ and $8n +29$?
For each possible common factor of $5n+16$ and $8n +29$ find the general form of $n$ that yields the pair of numbers with that common factor."

I tried to do this manually. I really got nowhere. I noticed that $n$ has to be a tad bit bigger than $5$... :)

Comment: Hint: If $d > 1$ divides both $5n + 16$ and $8n + 29$, then it also divides $8 (5n + 16) - 5 (8n + 29)$.

Answer (score 3):

Any common factor of $5n+16$ and $8n+29$ is a factor of
$$5(8n+29)-8(5n+16)=17\ .$$
Since you don't want a common factor $1$, it has to be $17$.  So you are looking for
$$17\mid 5n+16\ ,$$
and this is easy to solve by congruence methods.  I'll leave the rest up to you.

**BTW**, re your title - this is not the GCF of two polynomials, because $n$ is being thought of as a number.  If you were thinking of $n$ as a variable with no specific value, then it would be a GCF of polynomials.